# Validação ValidationSummary em um modal receber mensagem Json

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, json, validação

Minha aplicação tem uma **View Create** que é aberta através de um modal e o Controller que era um **ActionResult** passou a ser um **JsonResult** retornando então Json após a requisição **[HttpPost]**.

> As DataAnnotations de campos [Required] funcionam perfeitamente.

Só que nesta mudança algumas validações da minha antiga configuração, passaram a não funcionar mais, sendo ela obrigatórias.

Estas mensagens eram capturas pelo:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Como faço para o ValidationSummary capturar a mensagem que são enviadas via Json

Exemplos do retorno enviado pelo meu **Controller Create**.

```
return Json(new { resultado = true, mensagem = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!" });
```

Comment: Isso nunca vai funcionar porque a view não é mais carregada depois da requisição. Você vai ter colocar esse "summary" manualmente depois de receber a resposta do server.

Comment: É realmente percebi isto hoje antes de ver sua resposta, e você veio confirmar, valeu mesmo.

O que eu farei é o seguinte usar o toastr para minhas mensagens, mesmo que em alguns momentos tenha mais de uma mensagem de aviso.